# Template specialization for binary operator overloading - how to solve ambiguity?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, template-specialization

## What I'm trying to achieve

I have a class, `Foo`. I want to overload `operator+` so that:

```
foo1 + 10; // left +
10 + foo2; // right +
foo1 + foo2; // specialized
```

## What I tried

I'm aware that to capture the left and right add, I have to templatize the call:

```
template <typename T>
var operator+(const Foo& lhs, const T& rhs){
    return lhs.val + rhs);
}

template <typename T>
var operator+(const T& lhs, const Foo& rhs){
    return rhs.val + lhs);
}
```

and this works perfectly fine, until we have to specialize the case where both inputs are `Foo`:

```
template <>
var operator+(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs){
    return rhs.val + lhs.val;
}
```

This will complain about the ambiguity, and rightly so.

However, how do I implement what I want if I can't specialize that specific case?

Comment: Remove `template <>`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki wtf. That was the shortest answer I've ever received. Thank you :) You should write that in a post so I can give you some internet points (Also could you elaborate on why I don't need to do template specialization here? I have a general idea, that by removing the `template <>` it will not search for previously defined templates and allow you to just specialize directly since there's only 1 possibility here. However, I see people use `template <>` regardless of this. )

Comment: Why not to create constructor for Foo from T. In this case you do not need 2 versions with Foo and T - only last version that receives Foo and Foo. Also It is recommended to implement operator + in terms of operator +=

Comment: @OneRaynyDay *"... allow you to just specialize directly..."* - dropping the `template<>` doesn't specialize *anything*, it's an *overload*. You may find [**this article**](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) an interesting read.